# How do i open ros package on qtcreator

Tags: ros, catkin-make, qtcreator, qt, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a Ros package.
And I will try to open the package with Qt.
However, I get the following type of error.

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59
> (message):   find_package(catkin)
> failed.  catkin was neither found in
> the workspace nor   in the
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.  One reason may be
> that no ROS setup.sh was   sourced
> before.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/navi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

And my package CMakeList is as follows.

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> project(multi_xtion)
>
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   image_transport   rosbag roscpp   sensor_msgs   std_msgs  cv_bridge )
> set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "release")
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_LIBS /usr/lib)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_LIBS /usr/local/lib) 
> LIST(APPEND> SEARCH_LIBS /opt/local/lib)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_LIBS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /usr/include) 
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /opt/include)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /usr/include/eigen3)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /opt/include/eigen3)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /usr/local/include) 
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /opt/local/include)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /usr/local/include/eigen3)
> LIST(APPEND SEARCH_HEADERS /opt/local/include/eigen3)
> ```

> ```
> message("-- Check for Google Flags")
> find_library(GFLAGS_LIB NAMES gflags PATHS ${SEARCH_LIBS})
> >     find_path(GFLAGS_INCLUDE NAMES gflags/gflags.h PATHS ${SEARCH_HEADERS})
> include_directories(${GFLAGS_INCLUDE})
> ```

> ```
> find_path(EIGEN_INCLUDE NAMES Eigen/Core PATHS ${SEARCH_HEADERS})
> ```

> ```
> include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE})
> >     find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)
> >     message("CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> message("CERES_LIBRARIES: " ${CERES_LIBRARIES})
> >     include_directories(${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> ```

> ```
> IF (NOT "${OpenCV_DIR}" EQUAL "")
> >          MESSAGE("Using OpenCV from " ${OpenCV_DIR}) 
> ENDIF (NOT "${OpenCV_DIR}" EQUAL "")
> > 
> >     find_package(OpenCV 3.2 REQUIRED core imgproc highgui imgcodecs xfeatures2d PATHS "/usr/share/local/OpenCV")
> >     MESSAGE("Using OpenCV from " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> >     link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
>
> find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
> pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
> include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> >     message("GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> message("GLFW_LIBRARIES: " ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
> > 
> >     catkin_package()
> >     include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
>
> add_executable(multi_xtion src/multi_xtion.cpp)
> add_dependencies(multi_xtion ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
> target_link_libraries(multi_xtion ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> target_link_libraries(extrinsic_calib ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${GFLAGS_LIB} ${CERES_LIBRARIES} $catkin_LIBRARIES} -lGL -lGLU ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
> >     install(TARGETS multi_xtion
> >         RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
> )
> ```

**Catkin_make works fine.
What's wrong with qt-cmake?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256467/how-do-i-open-ros-package-on-qtcreator/) by [anonymous28394](https://answers.ros.org/users/28394/anonymous28394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try setting in the cmake configuration  (tools> options> Kits > (your kit) > cmake configuration) and be sure to start qtcreator from a bash with the ros environment configured

CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX:STRING=/home//catkin_ws/devel
CATKIN_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=/home//catkin_ws/install
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/home//catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:Cxx}
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:C}
QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=%{Qt:qmakeExecutable}

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2017-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a Plugin for QT that typically sets up everything correctly and works like a charm.
Have you tried this? https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin/wiki

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1